# how to switch to other layout in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

if i have 2 layout in my application how can change my default layout to other layout for some controller or action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$layout->setLayout('otherlayout');
```

Where `otherlayout` is the name of the second layout (otherlayout.phtml in your layouts folder).

Answer (score 7):

robertbasic's answer is correct. You can also do the following inside of a controller action:

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('otherlayout');
```

Comment: @Mark +1 still working, mine version is v1.11.11 :) upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion, It is better to use

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$layout->setLayout('otherlayout');
```

in your view rather than use

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('otherlayout');
```

from the controller.

The latter method has a bug. I had an experience where
I used

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('otherlayout');
```

and the new layout was displayed inside the old layout.
I used

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$layout->setLayout('otherlayout');
```

then it worked